# I get different (unexpected) results when selecting edges by edge attribute using igraph::E()[] and igraph::edge_attr(), why?

Tags: r, igraph

From a graph built with igraph, I'm trying to select edges by edge attribute, using igraph::E()[] and igraph::edge_attr(). Changing my code slightly in the selection condition, I get different results applying the selection. I find this unexpected. I can't explain it. Please let me know why.

```
library("igraph")

# create dummy graph and selection attribute
set.seed(42)
g <- make_ring(10)
g <- set_edge_attr(g, "group", value = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE))
edge_attr(g)

# select by
edge_attr_group <- "group"
random_name_of_variable <- "A"
group <- "A"
```

First, recognize that

```
# indices to select
which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == "A")
which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == random_name_of_variable)
which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == group)
# all equal and expected
```

So far so good I guess. But then applying the selection condition

```
# apply selection
E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == "A")]
E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == random_name_of_variable)]
# both equal and expected, but
E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == group)]
# is not equal and thus unexpected
```

So, selecting using a static value (*"A"*) or a random name for the condition variable (*random_name_of_variable*), we get the intended results. But when selecting using the *group* variable, we don't get the same result. What is the reason for this? I recognize that the variable name is the same as the attribute name, but why would that matter?

For reference, session info and my output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2  magrittr_2.0.3  tools_4.1.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3

> which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == "A")
[1] 1 2 3 4 9
> which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == random_name_of_variable)
[1] 1 2 3 4 9
> which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == group)
[1] 1 2 3 4 9
> E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == "A")]
+ 5/10 edges from 0e5f311:
[1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 9--10
> E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == random_name_of_variable)]
+ 5/10 edges from 0e5f311:
[1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 9--10
> E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == group)]
+ 10/10 edges from 0e5f311:
 [1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 7-- 8 8-- 9 9--10 1--10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because attribute names are interpreted specially when indexing into an edge or vertex sequence. This is described in the documentation [here](https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/igraph-es-indexing.html) and [here](https://igraph.org/r/html/latest/igraph-vs-indexing.html):

> When indexing edge sequences, edge attributes can be referred to simply by using their names. E.g. if a graph has a weight edge attribute, then `E(G)[weight > 1]` selects all edges with a larger than one weight. See more examples below.

Thus a simpler way to select edges from group `"A"` is `E(g)[group == "A"]`.

---

**Update:** Since R/igraph 1.3.3, it is possible to disambiguate names using the `.data` and `.env` pronouns.

Unqualified names are attempted to be interpreted as attributes. If an attribute of that name does not exist, the name is treated as a variable.

Thus, this selects the 3rd edge:

```r
> g <- make_ring(5)
> foo <- 3
> E(g)[foo]
+ 1/5 edge from febda41:
[1] 3--4
```

But as soon as we set an attribute named `foo`, its behaviour changes:

```r
> E(g)$foo <- LETTERS[1:5]
> E(g)[foo]
Error in simple_es_index(x, ii) : Unknown edge selected
```

To specify that `foo` is a variable, and avoid any ambiguity, we can refer to it as `.env$foo`:

```r
> E(g)[.env$foo]
+ 1/5 edge from febda41:
[1] 3--4
```

For completeness, we can also make it explicit that it refers to an attribute name:

```r
> E(g)[.data$foo == 'D']
+ 1/5 edge from febda41:
[1] 4--5
```

Comment: Although I kind of see why, I still feel that this is not intuitive. So then you may never pass any variable whose name is also an attribute name? Is there a way to check this? 

Perhaps very technical, but why isn't 
`which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_group) == group)` 
evaluated before indexing?

The reason for going the longer way is to add flexibility, say for example that you can't control the name of the edge attribute, ie 
`select_edges <- function(g, edge_attr_value, edge_attr_name) E(g)[which(edge_attr(g, edge_attr_name) == edge_attr_value)]`
What would be an alternative?

Comment: @R-ish A better place to discuss this would be the igraph forums https://igraph.discourse.group/ I see this as a tradeoff between usability during interactive work and predictability in the face of unknown input, which is important for library code. I opened this issue after reading your post: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/541 But I rarely work with R.

Comment: @R-ish Please see the update. This improvement happened in response to your post. Please continue providing feedback in the future.